# Проблема с добавлением коллекции в comboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

Имеется список

```
public class TransportCategory
{
    public int id;
    public string title;
}

List<TransportCategory> transportList = new List<TransportCategory>();
```

Заполняю следующим образом:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    transportCategory = new TransportCategory();
    transportCategory.id = reader.GetInt32(0);
    transportCategory.title = reader.GetString(1);
    transportList.Add(transportCategory);
}
```

Затем создаю сам бокс

```
ComboBox cb = new ComboBox() { Location = new Point(341, categoryComboBox.Location.Y + margin * count), Width = 146, Height = 21 };
cb.DataSource = transportList;
cb.DisplayMember = "title";
cb.ValueMember = "id";
Controls.Add(cb);
```

В итоге в comboBox столько элементов, сколько и в коллекции, но вместо значений 
что-то вроде `AutoPark.AddTransport+TransportCategory`. 
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Где то был дубликат, в нем рассказывается, что привязка к полям невозможно. Может кто помнит и закроет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если кому интересно, решил проблему добавлением геттеров и сеттеров в класс TransportCategory.

```
public class TransportCategory
{
     public int id { get; set; }
     public string title { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Если вы нашли решение для вопроса самостоятельно и хотите поделиться им, то напишите, пожалуйста, нормальный ответ с примерами кода.

Comment: @Bulson Я конечно все понимаю, но вроде написано корректно! За что минус ? Нужен код класса TransportCategory где стоят {get; set;}? Я "плюсую" ответ!

Comment: @YuryBakharev а что не корректно, то? Я, например, совсем не понял о каком классе идет речь. Это не ответ, а сообщение в любимом чатике.